# Web App Push Notification, Unable to Push the notification on browser

Tags: node.js, push-notification, dom-events, service-worker, web-notifications

I have been trying to push notification on my web app.
I have been following [google's codelabs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/) for assistance and I have been successful until I reached 'Handle a Push Event' part.
I did exactly what they had mentioned, where could I possibly go wrong?
I am new to this so please help and thanking everyone, who bothered to answer, in advance

My main script code is as follows:

```
    'use strict';

const applicationServerPublicKey = 'BEEbOQcOmPNlAHvkHCdVGPehs3y45L-30_71yyrRbxNRp7Q3bCEGWoCnq5dxeiB2nwGWfTc5BOrbEWsU2FGXgtk';

const pushButton = document.querySelector('.js-push-btn');

let isSubscribed = false;
let swRegistration = null;

function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding)
    .replace(/\-/g, '+')
    .replace(/_/g, '/');

  const rawData = window.atob(base64);
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return outputArray;
}

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
  console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  .then(function(swReg) {
    console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);

    swRegistration = swReg;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
  });
} else {
  console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
  pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
}

function initializeUI() {
    pushButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    pushButton.disabled = true;
    if (isSubscribed) {
      // TODO: Unsubscribe user
    } else {
      subscribeUser();
    }
  });

  // Set the initial subscription value
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    isSubscribed = !(subscription === null);

    if (isSubscribed) {
      console.log('User IS subscribed.');
    } else {
      console.log('User is NOT subscribed.');
    }

    updateBtn();
  });
}

function updateBtn() {
  if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Push Messaging Blocked.';
    pushButton.disabled = true;
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);
    return;
  }


  if (isSubscribed) {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messaging';
  } else {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Enable Push Messaging';
  }

  pushButton.disabled = false;
}

function subscribeUser() {
  const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
  swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
  })
  .then(function(subscription) {
    console.log('User is subscribed.');

    updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

    isSubscribed = true;

    updateBtn();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
    updateBtn();
  });
}

function updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription) {
  // TODO: Send subscription to application server

  const subscriptionJson = document.querySelector('.js-subscription-json');
  const subscriptionDetails =
    document.querySelector('.js-subscription-details');

  if (subscription) {
    subscriptionJson.textContent = JSON.stringify(subscription);
    subscriptionDetails.classList.remove('is-invisible');
  } else {
    subscriptionDetails.classList.add('is-invisible');
  }
}

navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
.then(function(swReg) {
  console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);

  swRegistration = swReg;
  initializeUI();
})
```

My sw.js code is

```
'use strict';
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
  console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

  const title = 'Push Codelab';
  const options = {
    body: 'Yay it works.',
    icon: 'images/icon.png',
    badge: 'images/badge.png'
  };

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
```

I am getting the following error message in my console :

Service Worker termination by a timeout timer was canceled because DevTools is attached.

Comment: please add code

Comment: Done. @Felipe Morales

Answer (score 1):

```
    'use strict';

const applicationServerPublicKey = 'BKqJnZ7e-r7DMOqpx2mm-BCWDCm1Urvt2KnwwmFe7v5QEfMMl139SlNGi6T6FSUmcNVJhXEI6_uLiauw1AFuMJc';
//BKqJnZ7e+r7DMOqpx2mm+BCWDCm1Urvt2KnwwmFe7v5QEfMMl139SlNGi6T6FSUmcNVJhXEI6/uLiauw1AFuMJc=
const pushButton = document.querySelector('.js-push-btn');

let isSubscribed = false;
let swRegistration = null;

function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) 
{
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
  //console.log(padding + base64String.length);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding)
    .replace(/\-/g, '+')
    .replace(/_/g, '/');
  const rawData = window.atob(base64);
  //console.log(base64);
  //console.log(rawData);
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) 
  {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  console.log(outputArray);
  return outputArray;
}

//1
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) 
{
  console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then
  (
    function(swReg) 
    {
      //console.log(swReg);
      console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);

      swRegistration = swReg;

      //console.log(swRegistration);
    }
  )
  .catch
  (
    function(error) 
    {
      console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
    }
  );
} 
else 
{
  console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
  pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
}

//2
function updateBtn() 
{
  if (Notification.permission === 'denied') 
  {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Push Messaging Blocked.';
    pushButton.disabled = true;
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);
    return;
  }
  if (isSubscribed) 
  {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messaging';
  } 
  else 
  {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Enable Push Messaging';
  }
  pushButton.disabled = false;
}

navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then
(
  function(swReg)
  {
    console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);
    swRegistration = swReg;
    initializeUI();
  }
)

//3
function initializeUI() 
{
  pushButton.addEventListener
  (
    'click', function() 
    {
      pushButton.disabled = true;
      if (isSubscribed) 
      {
        unsubscribeUser();
      } 
      else 
      {
        subscribeUser();
      }
    }
  );
  // Set the initial subscription value
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription().then
  (
    function(subscription) 
    {
      isSubscribed = !(subscription === null);
      updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);
      if (isSubscribed) 
      {
        console.log('User IS subscribed.');
      } 
      else 
      {
        console.log('User is NOT subscribed.');
      }
      updateBtn();
    }
  );
}

//4
function subscribeUser() 
{
  const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
  swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe
  (
    {
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
    }
  )
  .then
  (
    function(subscription) 
    {
      console.log('User is subscribed.');

      updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

      isSubscribed = true;

      updateBtn();
    }
  )
  .catch
  (
    function(err) 
    {
      console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
      updateBtn();
    }
  );
}

//5
function updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription) 
{
  // TODO: Send subscription to application server

  const subscriptionJson = document.querySelector('.js-subscription-json');
  const subscriptionDetails = document.querySelector('.js-subscription-details');
  if (subscription) 
  {
    subscriptionJson.textContent = JSON.stringify(subscription);
    subscriptionDetails.classList.remove('is-invisible');
  } 
  else 
  {
    subscriptionDetails.classList.add('is-invisible');
  }
}

//6
function unsubscribeUser() {
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    if (subscription) {
      return subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error unsubscribing', error);
  })
  .then(function() {
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);

    console.log('User is unsubscribed.');
    isSubscribed = false;

    updateBtn();
  });
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.